# How to Disable export button when click gridview edit button in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application i have export button when i click grid view in edit command i want to disable export button after it will enable. I disable export button in Edit command but when i click edit button it shows disable in minute seconds and after page post back it is enable how can i disable export button with or without post back  when i click edit command.
my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panl1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server">
            <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" OnClick="btnExport_Click" Text="Export" />
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" />
</triggers>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Width="100%" CssClass="mydatagrid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="header" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    EmptyDataText="No files uploaded" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnDataBound="GridView1_DataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" ">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="Btn1" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="mybutton" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/images/page_white_edit.png" ToolTip="Edit" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Please tell me thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your page before and after clicking the buttons in your gridview

Comment: Hi @CurseStacker, I added my gridview image when i click edit image just it shows disable and again after page postback it shows enable. In my gridview have filtering rows for using datatable plugin in that i added if no matching records found i disable the export button after normal position

Comment: In your page markup you aren't showing where the GridView is. Kindly include so we can see how your GridView is designed.

Comment: that is my gridview but i remove all the columns

Comment: Please share your Gridview markup along with associated events and from where you are trying to disable the export button. That will be more helpful.

Comment: We're asking for the markup <asp:GridView ID=....

Comment: Hi @suprabhat-biswal, I added this code for No matching records found when disable export button after that when i  click edit button export button not disable before no added No matching records found when disable export button code it work when i click edit in grid view export button disable

Comment: I updated my code please see

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `UpdatePanel` around `btnExport`, it makes no sense anyway since it's the only element in there and you cancel the UpdatePanel functionality by setting a `PostBackTrigger` to the button. Or place the GridView inside the `UPdatePanel` and keep the `PostBackTrigger`. Either way you can then just disable/enable the button on your edit commands in the GridView `RowCOmmand` method.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "mybutton_edit")
    {
        btnExport.Enabled = false;
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "mybutton_cancelEdit")
    {
        btnExport.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

PS the `<Triggers>` must be placed inside `<asp:UpdatePanel>`.